# Win10 Taskbar flicker when playing Civilzation 2

Tags: taskbar, windows-10-v1709

I've installed [Sid Meier's Civilization 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_II) on a Windows 10 machine, and installed the [XP64 patch](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/win-7-and-xp-64-bit-civ-2-mge-and-tot-issues-fix-inside.193215/) and the [unlimited patch](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/civilization-ii-unlimited.205794/) to made the old game running on the new machine. And it runs fine.

Then came the Creator Fall update for Windows 10 and since then only the taskbar is flickering while playing the game. I've updated the graphics driver and the system runs with the newest updates installed, but I don't know how I can fix this flicker.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hide the taskbar?

Comment: The taskbar hides already. When it is shows up it flickers, when it it hidden it does not. Setting the taskbar not to hide will stop the flicker, but that is not what I want. I also noticed that one cpu core is always under 100% load, while playing the game. Maybe that is one reason?

Comment: Try this patch instead: [Civilization II 64-bit Editbox Patcher](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/622154/).